# What will be faster-- EHCache or DB hit when both has same records?

Tags: performance, ehcache

It might sound stupid...
Suppose a scenario where there are 1,00,000 records in a cache with key as `someId`.
Now Database has 1,00,000 records witth primary key as `someId`.
My question is in this scenario what will be faster ?? Accessing the cache or hitting the DB with the `where` clause??
Let us suppose cache used is EHCache and DB is MySql.

Comment: May i know the reason for downvoting??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache is local and sits in RAM, db is remote and data sits in the disk (most often). Key difference!

Looking at [Numbers Everyone Should Know (slide #13)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//people/jeff/stanford-295-talk.pdf) you are looking at somewhere around 100-1000ns (read the data from the cache) VS 20000 ns (send 2Kb over 1Gbps network). So even excluding disk read the difference is already ~20 times. If you account disk read (10 000 000 ns), difference becomes 10 000x.

But these are all theoretic calculations; you need to do measuring yourself.